# How can I use ant <exec> to execute commands on Windchill?

Tags: ant, exec, ptc-windchill

Need to run this below command in the Ant exec tag.

windchill ext.cummins.securityLabel.CumminsLoadAgreement -d
%WT_HOME%/loadFiles/ext/cummins/Agreements/AgreementList/Agreement_Loader.xlsx -u wcadmin -p wcadmin

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Java Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) in your ant script to perform this.

Use the below script

```
<java classname="ext.cummins.securityLabel.CumminsLoadAgreement" fork="true">
            <arg value="${username}"/>
            <arg value="${password}"/>
            <arg value="-d"/>
            <arg path="${Your_Custom_Directory}/${Custom_file}"/>
        </java>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a your ant xml file, define a ant target with the tag , the path for Windchill Home is accessible with the variable ${env.WT_HOME}

```
<project name="YourProjectName" default="YourTargetName" basedir=".">
    <target name="YourTargetName">
        <exec executable="windchill" dir="." failonerror="true">
            <arg line="ext.cummins.securityLabel.CumminsLoadAgreement -d ${env.WT_HOME}/loadFiles/ext/cummins/Agreements/AgreementList/Agreement_Loader.xlsx -u wcadmin -p wcadmin" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

From a windchill shell you can then run the target as "usual":

```
ant -f yourFile.xml YourTargetName
```

Tipp: if you name your ant file build.xml, you even do not need to specify it as parameter.